# How do I set specific session timeout options for users to pick. PHP

Tags: php, session, select, timeout

So I want users to be able to pick from a couple of options when they log in. These options are for when the session will timeout. So if a user selects option 1 and logs in, 10 seconds later the session should end they should be logged out.

**HTML**

Side Note - This is just the HTML snippet of interest, obviously the form includes other things, like buttons etc.

```
<form id="logged" method="POST" action="thisdocument.php"> 
            <select name="options">
                <option value="test">10s</option>
                <option value="hour">1hr</option>
            </select> 
</form>
```

**PHP**

Side note - The code that does the actual timeout works fine on its own. So if I place it on the page with no options for the user, when the user logs in, it will timeout in the time I specify but my problem is to make this optional in terms of how much time they want to be logged in for.

```
                    $opt = (isset($_POST['options']) ? $_POST['options'] : null);
                    if ($opt == "test") {
                        $now = time();
                        if (isset($_SESSION['discard_after']) && $now > $_SESSION['discard_after']) {                   
                            session_unset();
                            session_destroy();
                            session_start();
                        }

                        $_SESSION['discard_after'] = $now + 10;
                    }elseif ($opt == "hour"){
                        echo "1 Hour"; //I'm just leaving these like this to save space. If we can sort out the first, I can just use it for the second option.
                    }else{
                        echo "";
                    }
```

So I'm not sure why but this doesn't seem to work and my beginner level PHP logic tells me it should. No errors are given. I only included a small amount of the code, the parts of which are of interest. I figured the smaller the post the cleaner it is and the more likely it will be for people to see the error.

Comment: Can you echo the `$_SESSION['discard_after']` and `$now` to test the output before you compare ?

Comment: Do you mean there might be something wrong with the outputs? The code works on its own, just not within the option if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have another `session_start();` lines before these codes, so when the `if (isset($_SESSION['discard_after']) && $now > $_SESSION['discard_after'])`

inside of this IF you should replace the `session_start();` with `header('location: login.php');exit;`

so you have to kick the user out of your authenticated pages.

PS: you can't use 2 times `session_start();` in on execution.

Comment: I don't have a session_start(); before my function, just on top of every page. When I add that code in, it won't log in at all.